# Error 1005 when Forward Engineering EER diagram

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, diagram, entity-relationship

I have created an EER diagram (as shown in the image bellow) in MySQL Workbench  and wanted to Forward Engineer to build the DB.

[image: EER Diagram]

After configuring the model options to the Target MySQL Version and removing the word "Visible" from all the Indexes in the SQL Code (the code goes in the bottom of this post), as it was triggering an error, I have came across a 1005 Error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `books`.`books` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `books`.`books`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`books` (
          `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
          `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `ISBN` VARCHAR(13) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`),
          INDEX `fk_books_book_prices1_idx` (`book_prices_book_priceID` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_books_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_books_book_prices1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`book_prices_book_priceID`)
            REFERENCES `books`.`book_prices` (`book_priceID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_books_transactions1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
            REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Any guidance on how to solve it is appreciated.

---

The SQL Code that I am using is the following:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema books
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema books
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `books` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `books` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`book_prices`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`book_prices` (
  `book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookID` INT(11) NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `currency` CHAR(2) NULL,
  `date_start` DATETIME NULL,
  `date_end` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_priceID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`transaction_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`transaction_types` (
  `transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_typeID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`transactions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`transactions` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_transactions_transaction_types1_idx` (`transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_transactions_transaction_types1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transaction_types` (`transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`books`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`books` (
  `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` VARCHAR(13) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_books_book_prices1_idx` (`book_prices_book_priceID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_books_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_book_prices1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_prices_book_priceID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`book_prices` (`book_priceID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`batch_transaction`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`batch_transaction` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_batch_transaction_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_batch_transaction_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`batches`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`batches` (
  `batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batch_transaction_transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  `book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `supplierID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`batchID`),
  INDEX `fk_batches_batch_transaction1_idx` (`batch_transaction_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_batches_batch_transaction1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batch_transaction_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batch_transaction` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`book_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`book_types` (
  `book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `batches_batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_typeID`),
  INDEX `fk_product_types_products1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC, `books_book_prices_book_priceID` ASC, `books_book_types_book_typeID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_product_types_batches1_idx` (`batches_batchID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_books1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID` , `books_book_prices_book_priceID` , `books_book_types_book_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`books` (`bookID` , `book_prices_book_priceID` , `book_types_book_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_batches1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batches_batchID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batches` (`batchID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`suppliers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`suppliers` (
  `supplierID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batches_batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`supplierID`),
  INDEX `fk_suppliers_batches1_idx` (`batches_batchID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_suppliers_batches1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batches_batchID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batches` (`batchID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`customer_transaction`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`customer_transaction` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerID` INT(11) NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_client_transaction_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_transaction_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`customers` (
  `customerID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NULL,
  `books_book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_transaction_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`),
  INDEX `fk_clients_products1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC, `books_book_prices_book_priceID` ASC, `books_book_types_book_typeID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_clients_client_transaction1_idx` (`customer_transaction_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customrs_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID` , `books_book_prices_book_priceID` , `books_book_types_book_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`books` (`bookID` , `book_prices_book_priceID` , `book_types_book_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customers_customer_transaction1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_transaction_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`customer_transaction` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`discounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`discounts` (
  `discountID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`discountID`),
  INDEX `fk_discounts_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_discounts_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`discount_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`discount_types` (
  `discount_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `discounts_discountID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`discount_typeID`),
  INDEX `fk_discount_types_discounts1_idx` (`discounts_discountID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_discount_types_discounts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`discounts_discountID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`discounts` (`discountID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`storagedistribution`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`storagedistribution` (
  `storagedistributionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`storagedistributionID`),
  INDEX `fk_storagedistribution_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_storagedistribution_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

---

**Edit 1:**
Removed `transaction_typeID` from both `books` `batch_transaction` tables and ran the following SQL Script:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema books
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema books
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `books` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `books` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`book_prices`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`book_prices` (
  `book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookID` INT(11) NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `currency` CHAR(2) NULL,
  `date_start` DATETIME NULL,
  `date_end` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_priceID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`transaction_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`transaction_types` (
  `transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_typeID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`transactions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`transactions` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_transactions_transaction_types1_idx` (`transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_transactions_transaction_types1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transaction_types` (`transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`books`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`books` (
  `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` VARCHAR(13) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_books_book_prices1_idx` (`book_prices_book_priceID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_books_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_book_prices1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_prices_book_priceID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`book_prices` (`book_priceID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`batch_transaction`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`batch_transaction` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_batch_transaction_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_batch_transaction_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`batches`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`batches` (
  `batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batch_transaction_transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  `book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `supplierID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`batchID`),
  INDEX `fk_batches_batch_transaction1_idx` (`batch_transaction_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_batches_batch_transaction1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batch_transaction_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batch_transaction` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`book_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`book_types` (
  `book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `batches_batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_typeID`),
  INDEX `fk_product_types_products1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC, `books_book_prices_book_priceID` ASC, `books_book_types_book_typeID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_product_types_batches1_idx` (`batches_batchID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_books1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID` , `books_book_prices_book_priceID` , `books_book_types_book_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`books` (`bookID` , `book_prices_book_priceID` , `book_types_book_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_batches1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batches_batchID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batches` (`batchID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`suppliers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`suppliers` (
  `supplierID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batches_batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`supplierID`),
  INDEX `fk_suppliers_batches1_idx` (`batches_batchID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_suppliers_batches1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batches_batchID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batches` (`batchID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`customer_transaction`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`customer_transaction` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerID` INT(11) NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_client_transaction_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_transaction_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`customers` (
  `customerID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NULL,
  `books_book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_transaction_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`),
  INDEX `fk_clients_products1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC, `books_book_prices_book_priceID` ASC, `books_book_types_book_typeID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_clients_client_transaction1_idx` (`customer_transaction_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customrs_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID` , `books_book_prices_book_priceID` , `books_book_types_book_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`books` (`bookID` , `book_prices_book_priceID` , `book_types_book_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customers_customer_transaction1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_transaction_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`customer_transaction` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`discounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`discounts` (
  `discountID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`discountID`),
  INDEX `fk_discounts_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_discounts_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`discount_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`discount_types` (
  `discount_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `discounts_discountID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`discount_typeID`),
  INDEX `fk_discount_types_discounts1_idx` (`discounts_discountID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_discount_types_discounts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`discounts_discountID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`discounts` (`discountID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`storagedistribution`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`storagedistribution` (
  `storagedistributionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`storagedistributionID`),
  INDEX `fk_storagedistribution_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_storagedistribution_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

And now I got the same error in the table `book_types`:

```
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `books`.`book_types` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `books`.`book_types`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`book_types` (
          `book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
          `books_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `books_book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `books_book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `batches_batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`book_typeID`),
          INDEX `fk_product_types_products1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC, `books_book_prices_book_priceID` ASC, `books_book_types_book_typeID` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_product_types_batches1_idx` (`batches_batchID` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_books1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID` , `books_book_prices_book_priceID` , `books_book_types_book_typeID`)
            REFERENCES `books`.`books` (`bookID` , `book_prices_book_priceID` , `book_types_book_typeID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_batches1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`batches_batchID`)
            REFERENCES `books`.`batches` (`batchID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed
```

Comment: Is the code generated by workbench or did you write it yourself?  If workbench, ensure your versions match between the server and workbench, as I find it weird that it would create invalid code.

Comment: On the other end, why link book and transaction_types?  This is not needed since by linking the transaction itself, you can deduce the type.  That might be the source of the problem...?  And such setup does not respect 2NF since the type of transaction does not define a book, it defines a transaction.  That comment applies to many other fields (ex. storagedistribution).  Apply at least 1,2 and 3 Normal Forms to your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by updating the relationships in the diagram.

The first diagram was denormalized, which isn't necessarily bad if there are justifications for it (the consistency was enforced by the FK constraint).

I ended up referencing only the PK of the "parent" table, being the `_types` table a parent one.

Final diagram:

[image: Final EER Diagram]

Answer (score 2):

```
FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID`, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID`, `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
```

Assuming you have good reasons to store `transaction_typeID` in the `books` table, though it's functionally dependend on `transactionID`. Any foreign key constraint needs an index in both tables (referencing/child and referenced/parent) which can support the constraint check.

If no supporting index is found in the child table (`books`), the engine will create one. That's why you have the following index:

```
INDEX `fk_books_transactions1_idx` (
    `transactions_transactionID` ASC,
    `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC
)
```

But the engine will not create an index in the parent table (`transactions`). Indexes you already have are:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
INDEX `fk_transactions_transaction_types1_idx` (`transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
```

Neither of them can support the FK constraint. So you need to define a new index in the `transactions` table:

```
INDEX (`transactionID`, `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
```

However - That is a denormalized design, which isn't something bad, if you have good reasons for it, since the consistency is enforced by the FK constraint. But if you know no good reasons for storing `transaction_typeID` in the `books` table, you should just remove it and change the FK constraint to

```
FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID`) REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID`)
```

Now it's referencing the primary key of the parent table. This is a basic design for foreign keys, and the constraint is supported by the PRIMARY KEY (index).

Comment: I have followed the normalized way and removed the transaction_typeID from the tables `books` and `batch_transaction`. Now the same error applies to the table `book_types` as one can see in the Edit 1 (with the SQL Script and error)

Comment: @GoncaloPeres In a basic design you should only reference the primary key of the "parent" table. And should probably rethink the entire design. I don't that `books` is a parent table of `book_types`. It's usually the other way around.

Comment: I ended up changing the diagram, reconsidering the relationships and now everything is up and running (and the Forward Engineering didn't give any errors).

Comment: @GoncaloPeres My answer is about the specific error due to a compsite foreign key without a corresponding index in the parent table. The fact that you might have mixed up the direction of relations is another story. I'm glad that you could fix it, but it doesn't need to be handled in this answer. You can though write your own answer and accept it - I wouldn't complain.